# switch function variable not showing

Tags: php, switch-statement

I've got this switch function that is suppose to get the value of a parameter passed in a query string, and upon it decide the value of the variable:

```
<?php

switch($_REQUEST['textcolor']){
case "white":
$textcolor = $white;
break;
case "black":
$textcolor = $black;
break;
}

?>
```

The `$_REQUEST` gets it's value from this link:

```
 <a href="index2.php?status=Busy&codigo2=<?php echo $codigo2; ?>&textcolor=white">
```

and this is the form in which I have a hidden element that;s suppose to show the value, but does not:

```
 <form>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?= $textcolor ?>">
        </form>
```

Any ideas why the `$textcolor` variable is not showing?

**EDIT:** Solved, the reason was indeed variable not declared. Thanks!

Comment: What are `$white` or `$black`? Are they declared previously?

Comment: Look at the comment below-tried declaring them before with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch($_REQUEST['textcolor']){
    case "white":
        $textcolor = $white;
        break;
    case "black":
        $textcolor = $black;
        break;
}
```

Where are $white and $black defined?

**EDIT**

Do:

```
$white = 'white';
$black = 'black';

switch($_REQUEST['textcolor']){
    case "white":
        $textcolor = $white;
        break;
    case "black":
        $textcolor = $black;
        break;
}
```

and see what happens

Comment: Somewhere after: `$white = imagecolorallocate($image2, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($image2, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image2, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Treid inserting the variables before the function-no go.

Comment: They have to be declared before in order to be used.

Comment: If they're defined later in your code, then they're not defined at the point where you need them.... ie in your switch statement. Define them before the switch.

Comment: As you can see above-I TRIED, IT STILL DIDN'T WORK.

Answer (score 1):

Add a last `case` in the `switch`

```
default:
   die('textcolor is not '.$black.' or '.$white);
break;
```